# Difference between new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } and new { @class = "form-control" }

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper

I wrote the control myself (not by scaffolding) this way:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => Model.Title, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

the control didn't render the the class `form-control` but when I changed it to:

`@Html.EditorFor(m => Model.Title, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })`

rendered the required class. 
the `LabelFor` control uses the first parameter signature and works fine.

There is similar question but no helpful answer:

[Difference between htmlAttributes: new { @class = "class1" }, new {htmlAttributes = new {@class = "class2"}} and new {@class = "class3"}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37387001/difference-between-htmlattributes-new-class-class1-new-htmlattribute)

There is a difference in the parameteres definitions in both controls:
the `LabelFor` parameter is

> object htmlAttributes

whereas the `EditorFor` parameter is

> object additionalViewData

I can't understand the difference, why not just using `htmlAttributes` object with `EditorFor`

Comment: The 2nd parameter of  `EditorFor()` is additional `ViewData` and you cannot add html attributes using the first syntax. [MVC-5.1](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/releases/mvc51-release-notes) introduced the 2nd syntax to allow you to pass attributes as additional `ViewData`

Comment: And the reason you cannot pass it directly is because `EditorFor()` was designed for creating you own templates - it could contain multiple elements so there is no way to know which of those elements you wanted to add the class name to.